# Mark's development of character in Operating Systems

Tags: character, the-social-network

Mark stays near the back of his Operating Systems class. He receives a note in class that is passed to him from the front. He then storms out and answers the professor's question accurately.

Here is a [Youtube clip of the scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3Rt2_9d7Jg):

Do these actions funnel into the narrative of his Asperger's and introvert outcast nature as someone who's a total jerk with no social chemistry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these particular actions give more insight in his character. But it is only character development in the perspective of the audience. Those actions do not seem to be part of his own character development: after this class, I think he still is who he was.

Answer (score 8):

I think the key point of that scene is to demonstrate that Mark's knowledge vis-à-vis computers and programming was leaps and bounds ahead of his peers. (Mark did, in fact, start programming at a relatively young age, and excelled in science and math in school.)

Comment: I think the scene is also about: (2) Showing Mark goes his own way when he leaves the room to spend his time on more important things, and (3) Mark realizing that such notes should be able to spread on The Facebook too. But besides all that, I don't think this is what is being asked by OP.